# Reaching the referenced text from a Word interop field object

Tags: ms-word, office-interop, word-interop

I am using Word interop to build a Word plugin. In this plugin I have a case where I want to examine all
Field objects in the document and when that field is a cross-reference to another place in the same document I need to be able to capture the text in the paragraph that the field is referring to.

I was able to get the name of the field object but there were no bookmarks defined in the Document although in Word I could click on the field to get to the other location.

*Example field*
[image: example field]

*Example field as code*
[image: example field as code]

*referenced text I need to get*
[image: referenced text I need to get]

*No Bookmark objects are defined*
[image: No Bookmark objects are defined]

I tried to simulate the user clicking on the field by invoking DoClick() on it and then I accessed V_V_Scalar_Document_Generic.Application.Selection.Range.Text
but it gave nothing. I also tried the GoTo approach below but still didn't reach the referenced text.

```
 System.Collections.Generic.List<string> L_V_List_String_Fields = new System.Collections.Generic.List<string>();
    foreach (Field L_V_Scalar_Field_Item in V_V_Scalar_Document_Generic.Range.Fields)
    {
        try
        {
            if (L_V_Scalar_Field_Item.Type == WdFieldType.wdFieldRef)
                // L_V_Scalar_Field_Item.Data --> gives COM exception
                // L_V_Scalar_Field_Item.Code.ID --> blanks
                // L_V_Scalar_Field_Item.DoClick() 'will not help because fields are not always hyperlinks
                // L_V_Scalar_Field_Item.Result.Text --> gives the text of the field itself

                // all variations I tried for the target parameter in the line below (last param) are not working
                // V_V_Scalar_Document_Generic.[GoTo](Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdGoToItem.wdGoToField, System.Type.Missing, System.Type.Missing, "_Ref28680085")
                // Dim L_V_Scalar_String_Source as string = V_V_Scalar_Document_Generic.Application.Selection.Range.Text

                L_V_List_String_Fields.Add($"CodeText:{L_V_Scalar_Field_Item.Code.Text} |FieldType:{L_V_Scalar_Field_Item.Type} |FieldKind:{L_V_Scalar_Field_Item.Kind} |SourceText:{"source text ??"}");
        }
        catch (Exception L_V_Scalar_Exception_Generic)
        {
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The bookmarks are not listed because Word has a convention that bookmarks with names starting with an underscore ("_") are "hidden". In the Insert->Links->Bookmark dialog box, you can see them if you check the "Hidden Bookmarks" box, but in the Find and Replace box, you have to enter the name manually.

Even when Bookmarks are hidden, you can reference them. So for example you should be able to do something like this (this is VBA syntax):

```
Dim TargetText As String
TargetText = ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("_Ref28680085").Range.Text
```

to get the text "covered" by the bookmark. In theory, you could use Goto, by using wdGotoBookmark instead of wdGotoField, except that I think it will only have a chance of working with the Selection object, not a Range object.

Depending on what type of cross-reference the user inserts, Word "covers" different parts of the referenced material. So you may need to construct the Range you really need, e.g. using the Bookmark's Range.Start to tell you which paragraph the reference is pointing at.